# Cannot invoke "UserRepository.findByEmail(String)" because "this.user_repository" is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm creating a Java API and I'm receiving this error in security filter:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "school.pachecos.api.users.UserRepository.findByEmail(String)" because "this.user_repository" is null

I have this code:

**Security Filter**

```
@Component
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    TokenService token_service = new TokenService();
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository user_repository;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filter_chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = getToken(request);
        if(token != null){
            String token_subject = token_service.getTokenSubject(token);
            UserDetails user_entity = user_repository.findByEmail(token_subject);
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user_entity, null, user_entity.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filter_chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getToken(HttpServletRequest request){
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(token == null){
            return null;
        }
        return token.replace("Bearer", "");
    }

}
```

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(http_request -> http_request
                .requestMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(new SecurityFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration auth_config) throws Exception {
        return auth_config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**Token Config**

```
@Service
public class TokenService {

    private final String secret = "b0eMdsHE5jKDW9RsjuC5VrF8BT7P2oHubObbdBvaVbfzlXgKftxQ2WrZfX4RtU04";
    private final String ISSUER = "API Pacheco's School";

    public String createToken(UserEntity user){
        try {
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
            return JWT.create()
                    .withIssuer(ISSUER)
                    .withExpiresAt(getExpiresAt())
                    .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                    .sign(algorithm);
        } catch (JWTCreationException exception){
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Instant getExpiresAt(){
        return LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("-03:00"));
    }

    public String getTokenSubject(String token){
        try {
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
            return JWT.require(algorithm)
                    .withIssuer(ISSUER)
                    .build()
                    .verify(token)
                    .getSubject();
        } catch (JWTVerificationException exception){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**User Repository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE " +
        "u.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%') " +
        "OR u.birth_date = :date " +
        "OR u.email LIKE CONCAT('%', :email, '%') " +
        "OR cellphone LIKE CONCAT('%', :cellphone, '%') "
    )
    Collection<UserEntity> searchUsers(String name, LocalDate date, String email, String cellphone);

    UserDetails findByEmail(String email);
}
```

I've had the same error with the Token Service in Security Filter, but as it is a class I've just create it with `new`, but I can't do it with `user_repository`. Any idea?

Comment: Where's the @Repository annotation for you JpaRepository?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a solution

I've initialized `new SecurityFilter()` inside spring security function:

`.addFilterBefore(new SecurityFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`

instead I should have put it as `@Autowired`:

**Security Configurations**

```
@Autowired
SecurityFilter security_filter;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several wrongs in this code and im going to point them out.

First and foremost, im going to point out the biggest problem. You are using a security framework (spring security) that has a lot of pre built security standards built in. *Basic* login, *FormLogin*, *Oauth2*, *SAML*, *mTLS* etc. But you have chosen to ignore all of these prebuilt standards and decided to build some sort of custom security solution, that hands out JWTs straight to browsers, and uses these as sessions.

This type of authentication you have built is sort of similar to the [*Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-resource-owner-password-cre) or the [*implicit grant*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#autoid-41) defined by the [Oauth2 rfc6749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749).

**Both of these authentication types have been deemed either as [MUST NOT BE USED](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-resource-owner-password-cre) or [SHOULD NOT BE USED](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-implicit-grant) because multiple serious vulnerabilities have been found in relation to them.**

So the point here is that this type authentication should not be built into new systems as of 2023.

Now to the more technical problems of your code.

You have annotated your custom filter `@Component` which means this class will be picked up by the spring context and added as a `Bean` when the server starts up and scans all classes that are below the main class in the file tree.

Only *spring beans* can use the `Autowire` annotation, because how would spring know what class to know to autowire in if its not spring that instantiates your class?

You are also then later calling `new SecurityFilter()` meaning that you are instantiating the class manually so spring has absolutely no idea at all what that class is, and ofc your autowired fields are going to return null.

You have to pick one or the other

- Either you let spring manage your bean (recommended).
- You instantiate your class and supply classes through a constructor.

This is basic spring bean knowledge and i suggest you read up on the basics.

And as mentioned before, this entire security implementation should be removed. JWTs should not be used as sessions.

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens

https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/

[http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/)

[http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/)

Sadly there are too many bloggers out there writing tutorials, and making youtube videos that have no idea how real security works, and that never even read the spring security documentation.

[Springs own recommendations for implementing SPA applications](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297)

Comment: Hey men, thanks for the explanation. As you've said, i got this way of security in internet courses and youtube, and i had no ideia that it was so bad. It's not for a company or anything, just a personal program, so it doesn't matter a lot now, but of course i'll change in the future to put it in my repository in a correctly way. Thanks for the time spent and the security explanations.